# Showing ViewController's View when animating upper ViewController

Tags: swift, animation, cgaffinetransform, dismissviewcontroller

I have ViewController(1) presented over another ViewController(2), I want to accomplish the effect that when I dismiss viewController1 I perform a reduction of size through CGAffineTransform and I dismiss it.

The effect I want to accomplish though is that when I reduce the size of ViewController1's view I want to see also the view of ViewController2 behind it, while now I'm only seeing a black background.

The code I'm using is really simple:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
    }) { (_) in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I don't know how to reach that effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to set this presentation for the top animated vc

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

This will guarantee transparency behind when you change frame / transform the view of that top vc